# Assign a name to a Java Sub Process (ProcessBuilder)

Tags: java, linux, subprocess, processbuilder

I want to assign a name for a sub-process that is invoking by a java application via the *ProcessBuilder()* in Java.

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder();

builder.environment().put("CLASSPATH", ""); // Unsetting classpaths

strategy.loadEnvVariables(builder.environment());  // set env variables to builder process

String[] invokeCommands = strategy.getInvokeCommands(); // get commands that need to start the sub process

process = builder.command(invokeCommands).start();
```

The above code is working fine. But I want to assign a name to that subprocess to see in "*ps ux*" command by the given name.

E.g

```
lsesv-s  27090  0.0  0.0 290168 25564 ?        S    10:43   0:00 /x02/lsesv-s/postgres/bin/postgres -D /x02/lsesv-s/postgres/datamhv
```

This is a sample subprocess that invoked by my java application and it gets passed commands arguments as the default name. But I need it to be visible by a name which I passed to the "ProcessBuilder()" object or any workaround to get visible?

Comment: Which of the columns in `ps ux` output is the "name" you want to set?

Comment: @Joni I need it to set in the command column.